# Sifr & Colorbox: strange gap in border of colorbox

Tags: jquery, css, sifr, colorbox

There seems to be a strange **gap on the left side of the colorbox** when it's **laying over a Sifr element**.

This picture shows the Sifr titles:
[image]

This one shows the colorbox being toggled on. Mind the gaps near the Sifr titles: [image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Could you provide some example code (preferably the CSS used to style those elements?)

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your elements floated?  sIFR is known to do some failry funky things in and around floated regions....  Dunno if it will help to put your sIFR stuff inside a container and then float the container without floating hte element...  messy and bloated but worth a try.

also, which browsers is this happening in?

I love sIFR but I really hate the fact that we can't include our own fonts using CSS; I hate the fact that the people who control the specs for the language feel it's necessary to restrict us in this way....  I read somewhere that it was an attempt at preventing unlicensed use of commercial fonts, but what's to stop me from using images that I don't have permission to use?  why not remove "background-image" from the css specs?  in fact, lets just remove h1, p, and a tags while we are at it in an effort to stop all forms of plagiarism.

my biggest gripe with CSS at the moment....